# Reading first 3 numbers in a 13 digit control number in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a program that generates a control number. Control number contains 13 numbers. The first 3 numbers is generated if the user is a maritime education, it is 100, but if the user is a general education, it is 101, then the following 5 numbers is a random numbers. Then the last 5 digits is the ID number of the user.

Code :

```
    Random rand = new Random();
            int startingDigits;
            if (CmbEducation.SelectedItem.Equals("Maritime Education"))
            {
                startingDigits = 100;
                string IdNumber = TxtIDnum.Text;
                string controlNumber = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    startingDigits, rand.Next(10000, 99999).ToString(), IdNumber);
                TxtControlNum.Text = controlNumber;
            }
            else if (CmbEducation.SelectedItem.Equals("General Education"))
            {
                startingDigits = 101;
                string IdNumber = TxtIDnum.Text;
                string controlNumber = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                    startingDigits, rand.Next(10000, 99999).ToString(), IdNumber);
                TxtControlNum.Text = controlNumber;
            }
```

My problem is, I want to make an if..else condition. but i want to read the first 3 numbers of the control number how do i do it? Thanks :)

edited :

I am using the control number in another form now for password. So i want to read the first 3 numbers to get if the user is a marine education or a general education.
Now, I am in another form, i just copied the text from the login page where the password is the control number to the textbox in another form. so how do i read first 3 numbers inside a textbox?

Comment: You should edit and update this question with the info from the comments under my answer; it does not currently make it clear at all what your problem is (variable scope).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm reading your question correctly, but if all you need is to read the first three digits, just do:

```
var start = new String(controlNumber.Take(3).ToArray());
```

or

```
var start = controlNumber.Substring(0,3);
```

It's not clear what you mean by "read inside a textbox". Do you want to read them *from* a textbox? Then try:

```
TextboxName.Text.Substring(0,3);
```

If you want to *place* them in a textbox, use:

```
TextboxName.Text = controlNumber.Substring(0,3);
```

**Update**: I'll give this one more try. This should be self-explanatory, assuming you've got `start` as above:

```
if (start.Equals("100"))
{
    // Do something
}
else if (start.Equals("101"))
{
    // Do something else
}
else
{
    // ...take a nap?
}
```

Comment: Now, I am in another form, i just copied the text from the login page where the password is the control number to the textbox in another form. so how do i read first 3 numbers inside a textbox?

Comment: I've updated my post, although I'm still not 100% sure I'm understanding your question correctly...

Comment: okay disregard that codes above that i posted, I want to read the first 3 integers in my Control number inside my TxtControlNum.Text.. example of Control number is 1011234522755. If first 3 numbers is 101, then it is a gen-ed education, but if it is 100, it is a maritime education. how do i put it in codes if..else?

Comment: `controlNumber` is not in my new form. how do i do this `var start = controlNumber.Substring(0,3);`?

Comment: Wow. Your original question is completely misleading. You have to find a scope that is wide enough for both your forms to be able to share that variable, and then define `controlNumber` there, so you can set it's value from one form, and read it in the other.

Comment: can't i just get the first 3 numbers from a Textbox?

Comment: Sure - if the textbox is within a context you have access to. That is a whole different question though, and depends on how you've built your application and your GUI.

Comment: so how do i do if..else with it? I have a textbox named TxtControlNum.Text. if first 3 number inside the TxtControlNum.Text is 100 then it is a maritime education, else if 101 then it is a general education.?

Comment: Please read through my entire answer carefully again. The solution is right there, and is not complicated. Hint: `var start = TxtControlNum.Text.SubString(0,3);`

Comment: `var start = TxtControlNum.Text.SubString(0,3);` i tried this. but substring has an error . Here's the error. Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length... it does not work with `SubString` but if `Substring` it can run but has that error.

Comment: It will give you that error if the textbox contains less than 3 characters. Have you checked that it is not empty?

Comment: yes it's not empty .. i put in 1012481822887. but still has an error

Comment: No, sorry, but I've already spent too much time on this. Also the question has evolved way off from the original. Make some effort, do some experiment. See what you get from the text-field, and what you can do with it, etc, then post a new question if you get stuck again, and try to be more specific about exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
       var controlNumberPrefix = myTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 3);

        switch (controlNumberPrefix)
        {
            case "100":/* Maritime education - do something */ ; break;
            case "101":/* Gen education - do something */ ; break;
        }
```

or

```
        var controlNumberPrefix = myTextBox.Text.Substring(0, 3);

        if(controlNumberPrefix == "100")
            // Do something
        else if (controlNumberPrefix =="101")
            // Do something
```

Edit:
Its the same thing with textbox. Just use the Text property of the textbox.

Comment: Now, I am in another form, i just copied the text from the login page where the password is the control number to the textbox in another form. so how do i read first 3 numbers inside a textbox?

Comment: Use the text property of the textbox.
myTextBox.Text = controlNumberPrefix;

Comment: `Non-invocable member 'string.Length' cannot be used like a method.` Substring has an error. why?

Comment: @LyndonBrozTonelete Are you using myVariable.Length() instead of myVarbiable.Length somewhere in your code? If so, remove the paranthesis because Length is a property.

Comment: `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length`

Comment: from this `var controlNumberPrefix = TxtControlNum.Text.Substring(0, 3);`